# Remapping keyboard (§ to `) doesn't work on some apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, bettertouchtool

I used this method to swap my (UK) keyboard's <kbd>§</kbd> key with  <kbd>`</kbd>.

1. Created this file: `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`
2. Added the following and saved

   ```
   {
      "§" = ("insertText:", "`"); 
   }
   ```
3. Restarted Mac

It works completely fine in every app such as Safari, Firefox, Finder, System Preferences etc., except in the most important apps, such as `TextWrangler` and `PHPStorm`. Is there any way I can make it work in them too? (specially PHPStorm).

*P.S. I've used `BetterTouchTool` to achieve this for a year (I only use it for this key swapping) but recently it keeps firing weird things, like in the middle of typing, suddenly a menu or popup related to that app opens (like it somehow triggers a random shortcut key or something) so I had to stop using it which fixed the weird issue. I'd really like to stick with native solutions this time.*

OS info: macOS version is 10.14.4

Comment: A custom layout made with ukulele should work with all apps.  Http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Comment: @TomGewecke I tried it, but no matter what I do, it always shows the keyboard with US layout (missing the `§` key completely...)

Comment: Do your mean inside ukulele?  You just go to the set keyboard type menu item and select iso

Comment: See if this one does what you need:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2m7jj13pog35op/BritishTilde.keylayout.zip?dl=0

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you very much Tom, I was able to quickly edit your layout and achieve what I needed. it works perfectly